# How do I use CSS to change tags with visibility:hidden to display:none css

Tags: json, visibility, hidden

On my site (no example, it's company facing), I am calling someone else's JS code that writes html to the page.  Unfortunately they are using visibility:hidden rather than display:none in an element with no class id.  I need to know the easiest way to target the elements with visibility:hidden and change them with display:none, preferably without using 3rd party solutions.

Is there any way to use css to target elements with certain styles already set, or to change the default behavior of visibility:hidden to take up no space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('selector').each(function() {
if ($(this).css("visibility") == "hidden") {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
}});
```

P.S. just edited my JS, now it works perfectly :)

Comment: P.S.2 if you know the class, you could just style it with the CSS, no need for javascript...

Comment: this looks for the visibility:hidden property; if any other value it lets it alone.